# Why is my if else statement being ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm writing a code that searches a dictionary for a user inputed key. To do so, I have the user type in their desired key, have the definition to that key be appended to a list, and then printing the list.

For some odd reason my `if serachT in dictionary` line gets ignored. The program will jump to the else, completely skips the if. I have removed the else to verify that the if does work. Any ideas on why adding else ignores the if?

```
import csv

def createDictionary():
    dictionary = {}
    found = []
    searchT = input("What are you seraching for ") 
    fo = open("textToEnglish2014.csv","r")
    reader = csv.reader(fo)
    for row in reader:
        dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]
        if searchT in dictionary:
            found.append(dictionary[row[0]])
            print(found)
        elif searchT not in dictionary:
            i = 0
            #print("NF")
            #exit()
    print(found)
    return found

createDictionary()
```

Comment: I've just edited your code to improve the formatting, but I'm not entirely sure I have the indentation correct. Please double check that the code above matches what you're actually running (especially the indentation of the `if` and `else` lines that you're asking about).

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but instead of that long `elif` statement, a simple `else:` would be enough.

Comment: Your code works fine for me as it is. Check @TimPietzcker's answer for other problems but with correct search term, it runs if-clause just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be populating your dictionary first, then start looking things up. Fortunately, this is trivial in your case:

```
def create_dictionary():
    with open("textToEnglish2014.csv", newline="") as fo:  # note the newline parameter!
        reader = csv.reader(fo)
        return dict(reader)
```

(Note that now your function name makes sense, unlike before)

Now you can do lookups easily:

```
>>> dictionary = create_dictionary()
>>> searchT = input("What are you searching for? ")
What are you searching for? hello
>>> dictionary.get(searchT)   # returns None if searchT is not in dictionary
goodbye
```